# Change Windows 7 Starter language

Tags: windows-7, language, language-pack

I recently purchased a netbook on Amazon, and weirdly enough it came with Windows 7 Starter German. I want to change the language to English, but am having a lot of difficulty doing this. If I understood correctly I need to install a new MUI, but can't find where to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Vistalizator overrides the limit of one MUI language on non-Ultimate Windows editions.

http://www.froggie.sk/download.html

http://www.froggie.sk/screens.html

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language from German to English is only available in Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate [according to Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that you are stuck with the language for windows 7 starter. See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-do-i-get-spanish-display-language-in-windows-7/cd1fe80e-5b6b-4f74-ae13-64ef421633b5).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not yet installed Service Pack 1, you can try using [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/) to install a [language pack](http://keznews.com/6149_Download_Windows_7_MUI_Language_Packs_-_Official_32-bit_and_64-bit_Direct_Download_Links). I had to use this approach when the display language of my tablet suddenly switched from my default language back to English with now way to "repair" it apart from ultimate upgrade or reinstall (And I didn't want to upgrade just because of an error by Microsoft).

I did this with Windows 7 Professional, so I am not quite sure if it works for the Starter-Version.